# How to merge items based on the same key/value in a python list

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to merge objects where one or mores keys have the same value.
Specific in my example I have a list where the category and code must match.

**Input**

```
[{
    "category": "Nace2008",
    "code": "01110",
    "NL": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden"
},
{
    "category": "Nace2008",
    "code": "01110",
    "FR": "Culture de c\u00e9r\u00e9ales (\u00e0 l'exception du riz), de l\u00e9gumineuses et de graines ol\u00e9agineuses"
},
{
    "category": "Nace2008",
    "code": "01120",
    "FR": "Culture du riz"
},
{
    "category": "Nace2008",
    "code": "01120",
    "NL": "Teelt van rijst"
}]
```

**Expected output**

```
[{
    "category": "Nace2008",
    "code": "01110",
    "NL": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden",
    "FR": "Culture de c\u00e9r\u00e9ales (\u00e0 l'exception du riz), de l\u00e9gumineuses et de graines ol\u00e9agineuses"
},
{
    "category": "Nace2008",
    "code": "01120",
    "NL": "Teelt van rijst",
    "FR": "Culture du riz"
}]
```

Looping through the list and do another loop to check for the same category and code will result in duplicate data.

Comment: what should happen if *other* keys match, or will they not?

Comment: In this specific case it won't happen. I'm currently working with hardcoded keys but if it can be dynamic with one or mores keys that would even be better

Comment: did you mean `"code": "01110"`?? Because your output implies you want to match `"code":"0111"` with `"code":"01110"`

Comment: The check here should be if other objects in the list have the same value for the keys `category` and `code`

Comment: My bad, I made a typo. Fixed it in the question

Comment: I would use a dictionary where the values for the keys is the key in the dictionary… for ex: `{“Nace2008_01110”: {object}}` then you could do look it up with a `.get` call and then add the new language key and value for each subsequent match. You could write it as a function so you can pass in the keys you want to check for uniqueness…

Comment: Seems the answer below shows code similar to my above suggestion, but using a tuple for the key, which is better! Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you just want the standard dictionary grouping idiom based on the key you described:

```
>>> data = [{
...     "category": "Nace2008",
...     "code": "01110",
...     "NL": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden"
... },
... {
...     "category": "Nace2008",
...     "code": "01110",
...     "FR": "Culture de c\u00e9r\u00e9ales (\u00e0 l'exception du riz), de l\u00e9gumineuses et de graines ol\u00e9agineuses"
... },
... {
...     "category": "Nace2008",
...     "code": "01120",
...     "FR": "Culture du riz"
... },
... {
...     "category": "Nace2008",
...     "code": "01120",
...     "NL": "Teelt van rijst"
... }]
```

So create an empty dictionary, group by the key:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for d in data:
...     key = d['category'], d['code']
...     result.setdefault(key, {}).update(d)
...
```

Note, the `.update` just merges whatever is there naively. If you would have duplicate keys in subsequent records, then it would take the last one. If they are all unique, it shouldn't be a problem. And the results:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
{('Nace2008', '01110'): {'FR': "Culture de céréales (à l'exception du riz), de "
                               'légumineuses et de graines oléagineuses',
                         'NL': 'Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen '
                               'en oliehoudende zaden',
                         'category': 'Nace2008',
                         'code': '01110'},
 ('Nace2008', '01120'): {'FR': 'Culture du riz',
                         'NL': 'Teelt van rijst',
                         'category': 'Nace2008',
                         'code': '01120'}}
```

Then you can extract the values of that dictionary if you want just that:

```
>>> pprint(list(result.values()))
[{'FR': "Culture de céréales (à l'exception du riz), de légumineuses et de "
        'graines oléagineuses',
  'NL': 'Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden',
  'category': 'Nace2008',
  'code': '01110'},
 {'FR': 'Culture du riz',
  'NL': 'Teelt van rijst',
  'category': 'Nace2008',
  'code': '01120'}]
```

Note, the grouping idiom can be cleaned up a bit using `defaultdict` (some people find `.setdefault` confusing):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(dict)
for d in data:
    key = d['category'], d['code']
    result[key].update(d)
```

Both are the same as:

```
result = {}
for d in data:
    key = d['category'], d['code']
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = {}
    result[key].update(d)
```

Comment: If the object should have another key `address` (completely random) and I want to keep them both by merging the two strings or two objects (if address is an object with `street`, `number`, etc.). Should I change the update function to a custom merge function to handle this?

Comment: @Thore yeah, you'll want to write a custom update function to handle things.